# Converting int to char, infinite execution

Tags: java, char, infinite, type-conversion

I can't understand why in this case program works correctly:

```
do {
        i = f1.read(); // i is integer
        j = f2.read(); // j is integer
        if (Character.toLowerCase(i) != Character.toLowerCase(j)) break;
    } while (i != -1 && j != -1);
```

but in this case program is executed indefinitely:

```
do {
        i =(char) f1.read();
        j =(char) f2.read();
        if (Character.toLowerCase(i) != Character.toLowerCase(j)) break;
    } while (i != -1 && j != -1);
```

I know that int to char can be implicitly converted, but if I convert it explicitly - it doesn't work, why?
Or I have understood something wrong?

Comment: Euh you compare `i != -1` in the `while` loop. But `i` is a `char`...

Comment: Please provide a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the behaviour.

Comment: Note also that the problem is not "infinite execution" - that's just a feature of your while loop.  The problem (if one exists) is simply that you're seeing a difference in the behaviour of `Character.toLowerCase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char` can never be equal to -1 (it's an unsigned type), so when you input -1 and cast it to `char` it becomes positive and the loop's end condition is never met.

i.e.

```
int i = -1;
```

and

```
int i = (char) -1;
```

don't assign the same value to `i`.

Answer (score 2):

As per Oracle Java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>   a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>   65,535 inclusive).

`char` can never hold negative values.
Therefore, the condition `while (i != -1 && j != -1)` will always be true and the loop will run indefinitely.

---

Also, when you try to assign `negative values` to a `char`, it will rotate that value through the other (max) end.

```
char c;
c = (char) 65;    // 'A'
c = (char) -100;  // 'ﾜ' and it results in 65,535(inclusive) - 100 = (char) 65,436
c = (char) 65436; // 'ﾜ'

int i;
i = (char) 65;    // 65
i = (char) -1;    // 65535 : notice how the char value cycles through the other end
i = (char) -100;  // 65436 : same as (char) -100. Here, int returns 65,436.
```

Alternative way to prove that `i` and `j` will never be less than `0` and the loop condition will always be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The required space for each **integer** variable is 4 bytes and the required space for each **char** is only 1 byte. Since each of these spaces are represented in  2's complement, The **char** variable **cannot** hold -1 in it's space(since it's unsigned) and it has to keep is as a positive value. Therefore it's better to keep your code logic and conditions using integer values.

Comment: A `char` is two bytes, not one.

Comment: @JacobG. I believe it depends on the character encoding type. I was using Java to develop some android applications and i faced this problem. I used UTF-8 encoding and it was **1 byte** large. But i guess you have a good reason for saying that.

Comment: The character itself can be one byte large, but Java uses UTF-16 as its default encoding, thus making every `char` two bytes.  This will change in JDK 9 when they switch to UTF-8 by default.